# Create apply-like Gui button

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

For example - here is non-clicked apply button (just default system window, no scripting):

[image]

After it was clicked once, it changes it's color and could not be clicked again:

[image]

Is there a way to create such apply-like button using AutoHotkey?

Comment: So you are programming you own GUI? Why don't you provide the code you have come up with so far and explain where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: Yes I know it's a best practice for stack overflow, to post the code. But in this case, the basic code (i.e. the code I come up) is so general (i.e. like code in the official docs), that I don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`GuiControl, Disable`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControl.htm#EnableDisable). Example:

```
Gui,Add,Button,gFoo vBar,Test
Gui,Show
return

Foo:
GuiControl,Disable,Bar
return
```

Comment: You could even make `Foo` generic for other buttons, using `A_GuiControl`.